# Parse Exception for special characters

Tags: java, json

I have a string `str` where

```
str = {"name":"vicky"12/3","pwd":""pwd":myPassword/123""}.
```

When I am passing the string in the `JSONParser(org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser)` I am getting the parse exception. 
Here `str` may vary depending on different input.

Tried with `JSONObject.escape(str)`. But then it is giving the error as Unexpected character `(\)` at position `1`.

Please anyone suggest so that parser will parse correctly and using that a `JSON` object will be constructed so that `json.get("name")` and `json.get("pwd")` will return correct result where `json` is the object of `JSONObject`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically that's not valid JSON. It's not clear to me what you *actually* want the value of `pwd` to be (should it be `pwd:mypassword/123`? Should it include quotes itself?) If *at all possible* I suggest you change whatever is *creating* the JSON so that you end up with valid JSON, rather than trying to handle the invalid JSON.

Comment: Just escape the quotes? `{"name":"vicky\"12/3","pwd":"\"pwd\":myPassword/123\""}`

Comment: json.get("pwd") will return "pwd":myPassword/123".

Comment: How to escape the double quotes(not manually)?

Comment: Use a JSON API to produce the JSON in the first place. My guess is that this text was created by something creating JSON "by hand" rather than using a JSON API.

Comment: Can you show us your code?